# how to find out the status of a file (checkedout, etc.) using Web Service Access

Tags: sharepoint-addin, web-services, check-out

I am currently trying to check out a file on our SharePoint server using the lists class that can be found at 
`/sites/storage/_vti_bin/lists.asmx` on any SharePoint server, as far as I know.

However, I need a function to find out the current status of a file, before actually performing a checkout. So how can I check if the file is already checked out using the Web Service Access as described here?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offic/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CheckOutUser column to determine if the item is checked out. Using the List.asmx GetListItems you can pass this field into the viewFields xmlNode argument. If it is not null then the item is checked out.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0c78a3d9-942d-4dbe-a74f-25055b873bd8/sharepoint-30-web-service-how-to-find-out-a-files-checkout-status?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: Thanks, the question is, what argument do I have to pass to the list class to get exactly the file I want? I know the path of the file, so how do I need to construct my GUID(?) to be passed?